# Tensorflow CPU Version Installation Error

Tags: tensorflow, failed-installation

I am running Ubuntu by using Virtualbox on Windows10.
I installed Tensorflow CPU version in terminal using `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow` as per instruction given in official site of Tensorflow. And when I tried to validate installation as `import tenorflow as tf` it showed following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

What should I do, to fix this error?

Comment: are you using `python` or  `python3` to test the install?

Comment: I  am using python...

Comment: `pip3` is pip for `python3`, so give it a try and see if you installed it there accidentally

Comment: Yeah!!! It's working now....Thanx for help bro...